# SQL - Multiple criteria MAX statement

Tags: sql, max, multiple-columns

I have a table with millions of rows, each of them with a timestamp.  I need a statement that checks a code and a date entry and finds the latest timestamp for both.  I tried the following query but I get the error "Column rownumber not found in t".

```
select 
code, date, other_crit1, other_crit2, timestamp
from (select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by code order by date desc, timestamp desc)
    code, date, other_crit1, other_crit2, timestamp
    from MyTable) t
where RowNumber = 1
```

I feel like i'm close but not quite there.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name the column.  I use `seqnum`:

```
select code, date, other_crit1, other_crit2, timestamp
from (select row_number() over (partition by code order by date desc, timestamp desc) as seqnum,
             code, date, other_crit1, other_crit2, timestamp
      from MyTable
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can call it `RowNumber` if you like.  I'm not thrilled with the name, because SQL result sets are unordered unless there is an explicit `order by` clause.

Comment: Super close @gordonlinoff.  only problem i'm seeing is that its not seeing every instance of the code and date per timestamp.

Comment: I figured it out. I added the date to the partition.